# Android Studio: Querying user data with firebase database takes time to load

Tags: java, performance, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a Firebase real-time database which contains data of users with the following structure:

```
AppName
  Users
    User1
      address:
      current_loc:
      dp:
      homeloc:
      loc:
      name:
      phone:
      username: 
    User2
      address:
      current_loc:
      dp:
      homeloc:
      loc:
      name:
      phone:
      username:
```

Now, In the app, i have used a search view which takes the query like this,

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if(s!=null&&!s.isEmpty()&&!s.equals(" ")) {
                    searchQ(s);
                }
                else {
                    resultList.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(new ArrayList<SearchUsers>()));
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I am taking the user data in a list and then comparing with the search query.
This is how i populte the list:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
       if(searchData!=null){
            searchData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            list.add(ds.getValue(SearchUsers.class));
                            SearchAdapter SA = new SearchAdapter(list);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(SearchFamily.this,"Error : "+databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

THE SearchQ method,

```
private void searchQ(String str){
        lav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        i = getIntent();
        i.getExtras();
        Usern = i.getStringExtra("usr");
        ArrayList<SearchUsers> Susers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SearchUsers obj:list){
            if(!obj.getUsername().contains(Usern))
            if(obj.getUsername().toLowerCase().contains(str) || obj.getName().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()))  {
                Susers.add(obj);
            }
        }
        SearchAdapter newSAdapter = new SearchAdapter(Susers);
        if(newSAdapter.getItemCount()==0){
            lav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lav.playAnimation();

        }
        resultList.setAdapter(newSAdapter);
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
The adapter takes name,username,loc, dp(profile pic),homeloc values.

This complete process takes 2-3 seconds to load. I currently have only 3-4 users. Is there an optimum way to search? If the user-base increases to 1000+ or so, what would be a better solution?